# Convert a textfield to a numeric value and then have a timer stop at that value

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, nstimer

I want a timer to stop at a user-defined input from a text field, then reset and repeat until it reaches a user-defined number of repetitions (another text field). This worked well when I was using sliders, but I was having some other problems with sliders so I changed to textfields. I think the problem is converting the text field into a numeric value, which I have tried many different ways without success. The app is a simple exercise repetition counter with a hold time. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you...

```
-(void)countup {   

float floatHoldTime=[holdTimeText.text floatValue];
float floatReps=[repsText.text floatValue];

CountHold ++;
displayHoldTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", CountHold];

if (CountHold == floatHoldTime) {
    CountRep ++;    
    displayReps.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", CountRep];
    CountHold = 0; 
}

if (CountRep == floatReps) {
    [Timer invalidate];
    Timer = nil;
}

}

-(IBAction)start:(id)sender {
Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(countup) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: What value are you getting from [holdTimeText.text floatValue]?

Comment: What data type are countrep and counthold?  Do you ever get the if statements to be true?  Also why do you use floats? Also comparing floats can be a problem.

Comment: What result are you seeing with this code?  You didn't say what's wrong.  Also, what types are CountHold and CountRep?

Comment: I have now made every variable an integer. When I run it I get a "Thread 1: Stopped at breakpoint 2" message in the countup method. My understanding is that the NSString class method intValue provides an integer from the user input, such as holdTime=[holdTimeText.text intValue]. I think this is the root of my problem...I hope this makes sense - I think it goes without saying that I'm a newbie. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should delete any breakpoints and see if it runs. The method, intValue, does convert strings to ints, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: intValue will give you an int and you can do a compare(==) of that to an int data type.  This should not be the issue.  First you should see if it runs and works and if not then set the breakpoint and step through each line of countup method and then comment here on where it breaks and what the error was.

Comment: Everything works now. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is that your float and what I presume is an int (CountHold) are never quite equal due to the way that floats are represented inside a computer.  Either make floatHoldTime and floatReps integers, or make you comparison something like CountHold - floatHoldTime < 0.01 to allow for a little slop.